# Form on submit always redirect to STORE function in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i am new to laravel i am trying to create a form with `onselect` from a dropdown it will take me to a resource control in which i have a function defined with name `getCurrency`.

Here is how my view looks like:

```
{!! Form::open([
        'id' => 'form_sample_currency',
        'class' => 'register-form',
        'route'=>'quotes.getCurrency'
]) !!}
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <select class="form-control select2me selectCurrency" name="user_id"  onchange="user_id.form.submit()">
                                            @foreach($users as $user)
                                                <option value="{{ $user->id}}">{{ $user->name }} 
                                                    @if(!empty($user->companyname))
                                                        ({{ $user->companyname }})
                                                    @else
                                                        ({{ $user->email}})
                                                    @endif
                                                </option> 
                                            @endforeach 
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

On select it takes me always to a store function.

Here is how i defined my routes in `routes.php` file:

```
Route::post('quotes/selectCurrency',[
                    'as' => 'quotes.getCurrency', 'uses' => 'QuoteController@getCurrency'
]);
Route::get('ajaxservices', 'QuoteController@services');
Route::resource('quotes','QuoteController');
```

And in `getCurrency()` i just returned dummy text;

What mistake i am doing, why its not redirecting toward the controller function i defined in the URL.

here is how my routes looks like:

[image]
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Instead of this in your routes file

```
Route::post('quotes/selectCurrency',[
                'as' => 'quotes.getCurrency', 'uses' => 'QuoteController@getCurrency']);
```

Try this

```
Route::post('quotes/selectCurrency',[
                'as' => 'getCurrency', 'uses' => 'QuoteController@getCurrency']);
```

Then in your form control use

```
{!! Form::open([
    'id' => 'form_sample_currency',
    'class' => 'register-form',
    'route'=>'route.getCurrency']) !!}
```

Comment: I tried but it says `route.getCurrency` is not defined. And even i remove the `route` then also its saying some route issue.

Comment: Can you change it back to the way you had it and open up a console and run 'php artisan route:list' then show us the output?

Comment: It looks like that route is using a get request. But in your example you have Route::post. I'm assuming it must be defined as Route::get in your routes file? If that is the case if you view the source of your form in a web browser check to see if the method is post or get, I bet it's showing post.

Comment: Try this with your form, assuming you named your route back to what you had it in the first place. Notice adding the method of get
`{!! Form::open([
        'id' => 'form_sample_currency',
        'class' => 'register-form',
        'route'=>'quotes.getCurrency',
        'method'=>'get'
]) !!}`

Comment: Yes i changed the route to `get` request.

Comment: Still its going to `store` method.